# prevent application from closing before all threads are done

Tags: multithreading, rust

So this is what I've got:

```
extern crate time;

use std::thread;

fn main() {

    let start = time::get_time();
    println!("Starting application");
    do_stuff();
    println!("Total {:?}", time::get_time() - start);

}

fn do_stuff() {

    for i in 0..4i32 {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep_ms(1);
            println!("doing stuff {:?}", i);
        });
    }

}
```

For some reason that I am not familiar with application doesn't wait for the threads in function `do_stuff()` to finish and closes. So this is the output I get:

```
Starting application
Total Duration { secs: 0, nanos: 808482 }
```

Instead of something like

```
Starting application
doing stuff 1
doing stuff 2
doing stuff 3
doing stuff 4
Total Duration { secs: 0, nanos: 808482 }
```

How do I make the application to wait for the threads to finish even when threads don't return anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spawn` function returns a `JoinHandle`. You can collect all the handles in a vector and call `join` on them:

```
extern crate time;

use std::thread;

fn main() {

    let start = time::get_time();
    println!("Starting application");
    do_stuff();
    println!("Total {:?}", time::get_time() - start);
}

fn do_stuff() {
    let handles: Vec<_> = (0..4).map(|i| {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep_ms(1);
            println!("doing stuff {:?}", i);
        })
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```